# Geometry: Find the angle x

Tags: geometry

I am trying to help my little sister do her geometry and seem to have forgotten my basic math skills. Here are a couple she sent me:
[image: Find the angle x]

[image: Find length x]

Any help would be great! Once I get back into the grove I should be fine. Too many years of upper division math has made my basic geometry go right out the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually don't understand the notion from the first one (are they referring to arc length there?) but the second one can be done using the Secant-Tangent Theorem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Trogdor, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

First, $ 25° + 148° = 173° $.  Since the ray going through the origin $P$ is a diameter of the circle, the total measure must be 180°, so the angle on the near side of the angle $x$ is 7°. Now to find the angle $x$ : $ 1/2( 25° - 7°) = x $,
due to the [Intersecting Secant Angles theorem](http://www.mathopenref.com/secantangles.html), so $x$  is 9 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT :** For no. 1, draw a triangle with the vertices on point $P$ (the center of circle) and two points on the intersections of the chord with the curve, let's say those two points as $A$ and $B$. Now, you will have $2$ triangles where $\Delta PAB$ is an isosceles triangle with $\angle APB=148^\circ$ and $\angle PAB=\angle PBA=16^\circ$, then you can apply a few of basic geometry principles to obtain $x^\circ$. I hope this helps.

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$